# Run tests from inner classes via Maven

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven-2, junit

I have following tests structure:

```
public class WorkerServiceTest {

    public class RaiseErrorTest extends AbstractDbUnitTest{
        @Test
        public void testSomething(){
        } 

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

It's done because I don't want to create a separate class file for every test case extending `AbstractDbUnitTest`.

The problem is that `mvn test` doesn't run test from my inner class. Is there is a way how to configure [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) to run such tests? Of course I can create methods in the parent class calling the inner class methods but I want a clearer way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the new (well, it's not new anymore) [`Enclosed`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html) runner (since [JUnit 4.5](http://junit.sourceforge.net/README.html)) that *runs all static inner classes of an outer class.*

To use it, just annotate the outer class with `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)` and make the inner classes static.

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class WorkerServiceTest {

    public static class RaiseErrorTest extends AbstractDbUnitTest{
        @Test
        public void testSomething(){
        } 

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And `mvn test` will run them.

Comment: I'm trying this with maven 3.0.4 and Junit 4.11 and still doesn't work. From Eclipse works just fine, but not with `mvn test`. Any ideas?

Comment: What works for me, was to modify the configuration of the "maven-surefire-plugin"... I put the following configuration: 
`<configuration>
    <excludes>
       <exclude></exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>`

Details at [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

Comment: @CarlitosWay  Can you give some details, it is not showing in your comment.  I tried including the src/main/java, and this still does not work.  Thanks.

Comment: There are a few limitations with `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)`: if the outer class (`WorkerServiceTest`) is abstract, the inner classes are still ignored. Second, if the inner classes extend the outer class (this is entirely valid Java BTW) the build will fail. 
The other solution - configuring `maven-surefire-plugin` excludes - does not have these limitations.

Answer (score 14):

I explain (a little more) the solution that I found...

Maven (AFAIK) uses by default the plugin "maven-surefire-plugin" to run any tests defined at your maven project. According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) of this plugin, by default, it excludes tests that are enclosed at inner static classes (or at least it was with version that i'm using - 2.18.1).

So what i did was to put a empty exclude rule; resulting with a pom's build section like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  ...
  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~ SUREFIRE -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude></exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: That worked!!!  I used surefire 2.19, but I doubt that was an issue.  I, of course, had to change the test source directory.  Thanks.

Comment: More specifically the documentation can be found at the [includes](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) section. Although I think the preferred way would be to use the `Enclosed` runner instead.

Comment: This fixes [JUnit 5 issue 1377](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1377)