# Why do the tests of the ATestClass of Spring's TestExecutionExceptionHandlerTests not fail?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Several tests in the test class of [TestExecutionExceptionHandlerTest#ATestClass](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-jupiter-engine/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/engine/extension/TestExecutionExceptionHandlerTests.java) throw exceptions yet I assume the unit tests of Junit pass just fine. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Could you please provide code samples and tests that are failing for better understanding?

Comment: The code sample is the inner class ATestCase provided in the link. Why does that class not have failing tests?

Comment: Please provide more details e.g. what tests are failing, what are the exceptions being thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47982480) explains it. More specifically the last comment by Sam Brannen:

> Maven Surefire [...] is not executing your static nested test class because of its default exclude rule.